# How do you change the header text of columns in an extjs gridpanel for localization?

Tags: html, localization, extjs

I found this useful [page](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Localizing_Ext) for learning how to do localization with ExtJS.

How can I apply the same principle to the column headers of a GridPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain your own own language file:

`Ext.ns('MyApp');
MyApp.Locale = {
    Column1Text: 'Foo',
    Column2Text: 'Bar'
};`

console.log(MyApp.Locale.Column1Text);

From here, you can overwrite it using new locale files, same as Ext does.

Comment: Thank you, would the language file then have 
Ext.override(MyApp.Locale, { Column1Text: 'Foo2', Column2Text: 'Bar2'};
?
I made a app-lang-ja.js, but this isnt being picked up...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When you say "isn't picked up", I assume you're including it properly?